# css textarea font-size out of control on chrome mobile, not font-boosting

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, font-size

I'm developing on mobile web pages.

But I found a textarea which font-size is not correct, absolutely out of control.

I'm now using Chrome on mobile or pc chrome emulation.

The placeholder text is correct, but once when I enter text inside, the font size is larger than what I set.

I know about font boosting issue, but I've set `max-height` on the textarea tag, with no luck.

Have any idea?

Comment: have you checked if the font style of the textarea gets overwritten from another style? Try give all the css elements in the textarea !important, just to test

Comment: Can you show us the website or at least some code? Have you inspected the element on mobile to see what happens? Is this issue happening only on Chrome only?

Comment: Got the same problem. Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**Works:**

1) setting height of textarea (ie style="height: 200px;"). It doesn't prevent font-boosting but prevents changing of textarea height after start writing. I don't know how to disable font-boosting in textarea - nothing seems to work.

*Doesn't work:*

1) setting font-size

2) setting max-height (as on other questions, which prevents chrome font boosting).